# Wordpress search and Filter API for IOS and Android

Tags: php, android, ios, json, wordpress

I am working on a project to apply filters on wordpress post...I have created JSON Output and Now I need to apply 5 filters that are as follows..
1. All
2. Today
3. WeekEnd
4. Next Seven Days
5. Date wise

Flow of the whole process...GEt Posts data in JSON--> Fetch This Data --> Create Filters---> User can Then Search as well as filter Data Further with normal wordpress functions....But I am not able to work out for fetching out posts by applying the Next Seven days filter and weekEnd..as the issue seems to be at my way of fetching the posts...What I am doing for now is

Code for Next Seven Days or last seven days...

```
   <?php
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php');
//require_once("config.php" );
require_once("incformfunctions.php");


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET"){
    $numberposts = isset($_REQUEST['numberposts']) ? $_REQUEST['numberposts'] : "-1"; 
 $posttype = isset($_REQUEST['posttype']) ? $_REQUEST['posttype'] : ""; 
 $securitycode = $_REQUEST['securitycode'];
 $mode = $_REQUEST['mode']? $_REQUEST['mode'] : "ALL";
 $taxonomy='art_categories';


if($securitycode == $secret)
{
$category_data=array(); 
 if($mode=='recommended') //to get recommended post of posttype category
 {  

        $args= array(
        'numberposts' => 100,
        'category' => 0,
     'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
  'include' => array(),
        'exclude' => array(),
  'meta_key' => '',
        'meta_value' =>'',
  'post_type' => 'events', //post name
        'suppress_filters' => true,
  'date_query' => array(
        array(
      'key'  => 'event_start_date', //custom name start date
            'after' => '1 week ago'  
        ),
  ),
  'meta_query' => array(
  'relation'  => 'AND',
  array(
    'key'     => 'event_editors_choice', //custom name event editor 
   'value'  => true
  ),
  'relation'  => 'AND',
  array(
  'key'  => 'event_recommended', //custom name event recommended
  'value'  => true
  ),
  ),

   );



 }
   $myposts = get_posts( $args); // get all value in array 
    if($myposts) {

    foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );  //and using foreach loop show all post type field
     $image= get_the_post_thumbnail_url();
     $featured_image =wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ));
     $start_date= get_post_meta($post->ID,'event_start_date',true);
     $start_date=date('F j, Y', strtotime($start_date));
     $end_date = get_field('event_end_date', $post->ID, false);
     $end_date=date('F j, Y', strtotime($end_date));
     $event_type = get_field('event_type', $post->ID, true);
     $event_venue = get_field('event_venue', $post->ID, true);
     $event_venue_address = get_field('event_venue_address', $post->ID, true);
     $latitude = get_field('event_venue_latitute', $post->ID, true);
     $longitude = get_field('event_venue_longitude', $post->ID, true);
     $description_long = get_field('event_description_long', $post->ID, true);
     $description_short = get_field('event_description_short', $post->ID,
     true);
     $gallery_address = get_field('gallery_address', $post->ID,
     true);
     if($gallery_address==false)
     {
      $gallery_address="";
     }
     $event_gallery = get_post_meta($post->ID,'gallery_address', true);
     $venue_address= get_field('venue_address',$event_gallery,true);
     $venue_postcode= get_field('venue_postcode',$event_gallery,true);
     $venue_city= get_field('venue_city',$event_gallery,true);
     $venue_location= get_field('venue_location',$event_gallery,true);
     if($venue_location==false)
     {
      $venue_location="";
     }
     $venue=get_post_custom($post->ID);
     $category=get_the_category($post->ID); //category
     $excerpt=get_the_excerpt( $post );
     $posttypes=get_post_type( $post );

  $category_data[] = array('id' => get_the_ID (),'title' => get_the_title(),'excerpt' =>$excerpt,'featured_image' =>$featured_image,'image' =>$image,'event_type' =>$event_type,'event_venue' =>$event_venue,'event_venue_address' =>$event_venue_address,'event_latitude' =>$latitude,'event_longitude' =>$longitude,'start_date' =>$start_date,'end_date' =>$end_date,'posttypes' =>$posttypes,'tags'=>$tags,'description_long'=>$description_long,'description_short'=>$description_short,'venue'=>$event_gallery,'gallery_address'=>$gallery_address,'venue_address'=>$venue_address,'venue_postcode'=>$venue_postcode,'venue_city'=>$venue_city,'venue_location'=>$venue_location);  // getting in all post array formate 

     wp_reset_postdata();
         endforeach;   
        $data = $category_data;
        $errcode=100;
     $errstr='success';
         }
       else       {
       $errcode=-1;
     $errstr='Post not found please check again..';
         }
}
//for securitycheck
if ($securitycode !=$secret or $securitycode=='')
{
 $errstr="unauthorise access";
}//end
} 

else{

 $errcode=-2;
 $errstr='Request method not accepted';
}
@mysql_close($conn);
/ Output header /
 @header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('errcode'=>$errcode,'errstr'=>$errstr,'data'=>$data)); // json create 
die();
```

Any Help on what I am doing wrong??

Comment: Post most relevant and well formatted code.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the immediate response..Formatted code...Can you help me find out the issue?